# craftyjs redraw on window resize

Tags: javascript, craftyjs

I am really new to craftyjs and I wrote a new game that created a full screen canvas. The game creates instance of board that draw a board with size of boardSize X boardSize:

```
var Game = {
        start: function() {
            Crafty.init();

            var boardSize = Math.min(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            Crafty.e('Board').board(boardSize);
        }
    };
```

I would like the board to be changed on resize according to the new window size. How can I do that?

Comment: `Board` doesn't seem to be a built-in component. Can you post its implementation as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subscribe on window resize event and change the Board component size accordingly. Example:

```
window.onresize = function() {
  var boardSize = Math.min(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  Crafty(Crafty('Board')[0]).board(boardSize);
};
```